# Change '\r' to '\n' for search and replace?

Tags: search, regular-expression, replace

In expression `:s/foo/bar\n/g`
When replacing `\n` inserts a null byte, according to the docs I have to use `\r`. Since I insert newlines more frequently than null bytes, is there a way to change this mapping?

So I want `:s/foo/bar\n/g` to insert a newline, not nullbyte.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this via a `:cnoremap <expr> \r` that checks (via `getcmdtype()` and `getcmdpos()`) that the current command-line is a `:s` Ex command, and you're editing the replacement part.

I would recommend against this, and just accept and learn that `\r` has to be used. Otherwise, you'll become dependent on your mapping and will struggle on systems that are not yours / do not have your configuration.

Comment: aren't we all ? I mean, I cannot efficiently use vim without my own vimrc.

Comment: That's why you keep your vimrc on github or bitbucket and pull it down to the new machine.